# Proton-Uranium collision

Tags: nuclear-physics, collision, protons

I am looking for references or numbers regarding what happens when one bombards Uranium with Protons. In particular:

- How to calculate how often does a collision occurs?
- Can a collision lead to a nuclear reaction?
- How much energy is released by such a collision/nuclear reaction?

If it can be of any help, protons are moving at about .6c

[Note also that this is motivated by [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/how-far-away-could-earth-detect-a-projectile-travelling-at-relativistic-speeds) in the worldbuilding site]

Comment: DO you have data like the mass of uranium and proton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the rest mass of a proton is about 940MeV. So, a proton at 0.6c is pretty darn energetic.  I will leave a precise energy up to the reader.

However, there are a number of experiments in the physics literature of smashing protons into various things. At low (1MeV-ish) energies, you are looking mainly at classic Rutherford scattering cross sections.  On top of that, one might have resonances with nuclear energy levels, either resulting in an increased scattering cross section, or nuclear reactions such as O18(p,$\alpha$)15N. But 1MeV is no where near relativistic.

For various reasons it is fairly easy to find data on 0.6 GeV protons smashing into things, mainly because the Paul Scherrer Institute has a nice accelerator to do it.  For example, the paper by H.U. Wenger et al. on 'A High-Fluence 0.6 GeV Proton Irradiation Experiment with Thin Uranium and Thorium Targets', Annals of Nuclear Energy 26 (1999) 141-148 might be worth a look (if you have access to it).

Basically, in this regime you can smash the nucleus apart, resulting in production of various mass fragments. The paper is mainly about measuring the cross-sections for production of fragments with masses from 67 to 231 from U238 and Th232. Cross sections were measured with both gamma spectroscopy (so you do make lots of gammas), as well as mass spectrometry on the targets after irradiation. Measured cross sections per mass number range up to about 100 milli-barns. The fission product distribution is shown to be 'broadly consistent with predictions' based on nuclear structure codes.

P.S. - don't try this at home!